setpgid: Operation not permitted error when running crontab in Alpine in Docker
Edit: Since this question was marked as a duplication of 68177789 I have changed the code to reflect the Sig's solution without any luck. Please do not close this question. The dupe has no answers.
I am completely new to Docker and Linux and I am trying to make a  simple Alpine based image that runs a cronjob every minute. That is, it  should pint “Hello” every minute.
Steps to reproduce:
Make a docker file with the following content:
# Use an official Alpine image as a parent image
FROM alpine:latest

# Install cron and any other dependencies you might need
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache dcron wget curl logrotate

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/crontabs/root

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/crontabs/root

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Add the wrapper script to the container
ADD start-cron.sh /usr/local/bin/start-cron.sh

# Give execution rights on the wrapper script
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-cron.sh

# Use ENTRYPOINT to run the wrapper script
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/start-cron.sh"]


Make a file called crontab and save it in the same folder as the dockerfile (note it must have a new empty line at the end):
* * * * * /bin/echo "Hello" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1



Make a wrapper script:
#!/bin/sh

# Start cron in the foreground with debug level 8
exec crond -f -d 8

Build the image with the command:
docker build -t my-alpine-cron .

Run the image and you should see the error message:
2024-07-28 13:10:44 setpgid: Operation not permitted

Why am I getting this error? What can I do to solve it?
OS Version/build: Windows 10 x64
App version: Docker Desktop 4.32.0

Why are you using dcron rather than the crond that's already available in alpine?
